# SP2010 - CEWP not executing javascript until page refresh

Tags: javascript, content-editor-web-part

The CEWP is loading a HTML page stored in the Site Assets library. The HTML contains a few inputs and some Javascript.

Javascript is:

```
 Function myInit(){
    console.log("here");
    Ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
 }
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myInit, "sp.js")
```

Normally this code runs fine if you navigate to the page but not if you open the browser from a link directly to the page.

If the browser opens directly at the page the HTML controls load & so does sp.js but the `myInit()` never gets fired.

============

Update:

I found even when using

```
 Function myInit ( ) { 
      console.log ( " here1 " ); 
       If (SP){
               console.log ( " here2 " );
       } else {
                setTimeout (myInit, 400);
       }
  }
```

It will only output: here1  once

Comment: Any reason you're doing this in a CEWP on page rather than running it in in the page head?

Comment: Because it is small tool inside a file stored in SiteAssets to be used on a single webpart page as a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

`sp.js` is probably not loaded on your site and the [`SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff411788(v=office.14).aspx) function does not force the load of a library. To load a library use the following: [`SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', callbackFunction);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592(v=office.14).aspx)

The diffrence as described in the MSDN:

**executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded**

> Executes the specified function if the file containing it is loaded; otherwise, adds it to the pending job queue.

**executeFunc**

> Ensures that the specified file that contains the specified function **is loaded** and then runs the specified callback function.

You need both to ensure that your script is triggered on every page. 
Here's an example:

```
function myInit() {
    console.log('myInit triggered');
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
}
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myInit, 'sp.js'); //this triggers myInit when sp.js is aviable
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () { console.log('sp.js was loaded by executeFunc'); }); //this triggers the function if executeFunc loaded sp.js and initialized the object SP.ClientContext - this does not necessarily trigger if sp.js is already on the page
```

Result on a page without loaded `sp.js` (an OOTB `settings.aspx` for example):
[image: result w.o. sp.js]

Result on a page with loaded `sp.js`: